# Comparación array y mostrar repetidos

Tags: java, array, método

Estoy intentando hacer un programa que me compare 2 matrices, una la introduce el usuario y la otra la crea el programa por defecto. Estas matrices son de 5 números entre el 1-6. La cuestión es que no se como mostrar los números repetidos y cuantas veces lo están.Lo que he hecho creo que mostraría cuantos números hay repetidos, pero no el numero en si.Ejemplo de lo que quiero hacer:
Programa: 1,4,6,2,6. Usuario:2,5,5,1,3.
Y el programa debería mostrar el 2 esta 1 vez, el 5 no está, el 5 no está. el 1 esta 1 vez, y el 3 no está. No encuentro la manera de que me cuente las repeticiones de cada numero por separado.
El método en cuestión es comprovarRepetido.

import java.util.Scanner;
public class mistermind {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     int matrizRecuperada[]=crear_tabla();
        for(int i=0; i<matrizRecuperada.length; i++){
         System.out.println(matrizRecuperada[i]);
     }
     int matrizRecuperadaPedida[]=pedirTabla();
        for(int i=0;i<matrizRecuperadaPedida.length;i++) {
            System.out.println(matrizRecuperadaPedida[i]);

        }
    }
    public static int[] crear_tabla() {
        int matrizDefecto[] = new int [5];
        for(int i = 0; i < matrizDefecto.length; i++) {
            matrizDefecto[i]=(int)(Math.random()*9+1);

        }
        return matrizDefecto;
    }
public static int[] pedirTabla() {
    Scanner entrada=new Scanner(System.in);
    int matrizJugador[]=new int [5];
    for(int i=0;i<matrizJugador.length;i++) {
        System.out.println("Introduce un numero del 1-9 :");
        int num=entrada.nextInt();
        if(num>9|num<1) {
            System.out.println("El numero insertado tiene que estar entre el numero 1 y 9");
        }else {

            matrizJugador[i]=num;   
        }

    }
    return matrizJugador;
}
public static void comprovarRepetido(int[]matrizDefecto,int[]matrizUsuario) {
    int repetir=0;
    for(int i=0;i<matrizDefecto.length;i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<matrizUsuario.length;j++) {
            if(matrizDefecto[i]==matrizUsuario[j]) {
                repetir++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Casi lo tienes solucionado el único error que veo es en

```
public static void comprovarRepetido(int[]matrizDefecto,int[]matrizUsuario) {
int repetir=0;
for(int i=0;i<matrizDefecto.length;i++) {
    for(int j=0;j<matrizUsuario.length;j++) {
        if(matrizDefecto[i]==matrizUsuario[j]) {
            repetir++;
        }
    }
}
```

Lo pondría así;

```
public static void comprovarRepetido(int[]matrizDefecto,int[]matrizUsuario) {

for(int i=0;i<matrizDefecto.length;i++) {
    //Definimos el contador a 0 cada vez que se valla a iniciar la comprobación
    //del valor 0,1.... 
    int repetir=0;
    for(int j=0;j<matrizUsuario.length;j++) {
        if(matrizDefecto[i]==matrizUsuario[j]) {
            //Si coincide sumamos una coincidencia
            repetir++;
        }
    }
    //Una vez se comprueben todos los valores de la segunda matriz
    //ya podrias decir
    System.out.println("El numero"+matrizDefecto[i]+ "tiene"+ repetir+ "coincidencias" );
   }
   //Aquí salimos del segundo for por lo que tu variable volverá a ser 0 y se 
   //comprueba el siguiente numero de tu matriz 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Una forma fácil de hacerlo es creando un diccionario

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Map<Integer, Integer> dictionary = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

    int matrizRecuperada[]=crear_tabla();
        for(int i=0; i<matrizRecuperada.length; i++){
        System.out.println(matrizRecuperada[i]);
    }

    int matrizRecuperadaPedida[]=pedirTabla();
    for(int i=0;i<matrizRecuperadaPedida.length;i++) {
        System.out.println(matrizRecuperadaPedida[i]);

    }

    comprovarRepetido(matrizRecuperada, matrizRecuperadaPedida);

}
public static int[] crear_tabla() {
    int matrizDefecto[] = new int [5];
    for(int i = 0; i < matrizDefecto.length; i++) {
        matrizDefecto[i]=(int)(Math.random()*9+1);

    }
    return matrizDefecto;
}
public static int[] pedirTabla() {
    Scanner entrada=new Scanner(System.in);
    int matrizJugador[]=new int [5];
    for(int i=0;i<matrizJugador.length;i++) {
        System.out.println("Introduce un numero del 1-9 :");
        int num=entrada.nextInt();
        if(num>9|num<1) {
            System.out.println("El numero insertado tiene que estar entre el numero 1 y 9");
        }else {

            matrizJugador[i]=num;   
        }

    }
    return matrizJugador;
}
public static void comprovarRepetido(int[]matrizDefecto,int[]matrizUsuario) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> dictionary = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

    for(int i=0;i<matrizDefecto.length;i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<matrizUsuario.length;j++) {
            if(matrizDefecto[i]==matrizUsuario[j]) {
                if (dictionary.get(matrizDefecto[i]) == null) {
                    dictionary.put(matrizDefecto[i], 1);
                } else {
                    dictionary.put(matrizDefecto[i], dictionary.get(matrizDefecto[i]) + 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for(int i=1;i<=9;i++) {
        Integer repetido = dictionary.get(i) == null ? 0 : dictionary.get(i);
        System.out.println(i + " -> " + repetido);
    }
}
```

Comment: Todavía no he tocado nada que tenga que ver con diccionarios. No dudo que sea muy sencillo pero gracias!